# java.util.InputMismatchException: error while trying to redirect txt file

Tags: java

I need to redirect a txt file as input into my program, however i always get the same error.

Whenever i run the code ill type in the name of the txt file it should use, however the same error always shows up.

**Here is my code**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] vector = new int[200];
        for (int l = 0; l < 200; l++) {
            vector[l] = StdIn.readInt();
            System.out.println(vector[l]);
        }
    }
}
```

**I am getting this error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: attempts to read an 'int' value from standard input, but the next token is "getallen.txt"
```

If i missed anything or need to explain more about my problem please tell me.

Comment: Can you share your full code this what you have posted looks good but it hasn't to do anything with reading file input. Hower the error says it will have an integer but it gets gefallen.txt looks like you read in a file name?
Maybe this will help you https://stackoverrun.com/de/q/10261897

Comment: How did you create `StdIn`? I get `error: cannot find symbol` if I try to run your example. Please edit your post to include the details needed to reproduce this problem. This includes a sample of your file, if you're trying to read from one.

Comment: _I need to redirect a txt file as input into my program_ How are you launching it from the command line?

Comment: >How are you launching it from the command line?

Im using intelij for java. So ill go into view -> tool windows -> terminal

,then i enter java-introcs test. Now i type: '> getallen.txt'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Princeton standard library, `StdIn.readInt();` will read in an Integer per the StdIn.read**Int**() part of the method name.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] vector = new String[200];
        for (int l = 0; l < 200; l++) {
            vector[l] = StdIn.readString(); // see edit here
            System.out.println(vector[l]);
        }
    }
}
```

You probably want to read in a `String` since that's what you are inputting into the terminal console. Also you should start class names with capital letters by Java convention :)